# Prove that the set of all endomorphisms of the group $\mathbb Z$ has only one element

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

The book on linear algebra I'm reading says that there is only one endomorphism of the group $\mathbb Z$.

Function $\phi_n$, which to any number $a \in \mathbb Z$ assigns a number $na \in \mathbb Z$, where $n \in \mathbb Z$ is a strictly chosen number, is an endomorphism of the group $\mathbb Z$.

How do I prove that this is the only endomorphism of the group $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: Hint: Consider the generator.